# How to group distinct values into a single level array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Is it possible to group distinct table values using an array of columns - to group by each individual column. For example:

```
$columns = ['column1','column2','column3'];
$array = Model::select($columns)->distinct()->get()->groupBy($columns)->keys();
```

And I would like this to return (obviously my code isn't accurate and i'd like a way to do this without a for loop... I feel collections have the functionality to do this):

```
[ 
  'column1' => [...distinct column1 values],
  'column2' => [...distinct column2 values],
  'column3' => [...distinct column3 values],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work. You had switched the places of `get()` and `groupBy()`

```
$columns = ['column1','column2','column3'];
$array = Model::select($columns)->distinct()->groupBy($columns)->get()->keys();
```